# How can I get a variable information in VBE , While my mouse point out it?

Tags: vba, excel-2010, vbe

How can I get a variable information in VBE , While my mouse point out it ?

[image: vbs code]

Comment: `Tools > Options` ensure that 'Auto Data Tips' is checked

Answer (score 0):

If you want to learn about the options available for watching variables while stepping through code, please refer to Chip Perason's page here:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx7

You can use the Locals window in the VBE to monitor variable values or use the Watch function to watch the values of specific objects.